# PostgreSQL 9.1 primary key autoincrement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to add a primary key with an autoincrement.

I have read some docs and other questions - there're `SERIAL` and `nextval()` statements but neither of them work.

Here's what I made:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "category" (
  "id" integer SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
); // the error near "SERIAL"
```

and

```
CREATE SEQUENCE your_seq;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "category" (
  "id" integer PRIMARY KEY nextval('your_seq'),
  "name" varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
); // the error near 'nextval'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to increment the primary key by 1.

Comment: You are defining "id" as INTEGER then SERIAL. SERIAL is a data type. PostgreSQL will create a SEQUENCE for you. You just need to remove INTEGER.

Comment: The table was filled with data before adding PK ?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`serial` is, more or less, a column type so saying `integer serial` is like saying `text text`, just say `serial`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "category" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

If you want to create the sequence yourself then you want to make the default value of `id` the next value in the sequence and that means saying `default nextval('your_seq')`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE your_seq;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "category" (
  "id" integer PRIMARY KEY default nextval('your_seq'),
  "name" varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

To simulate the usual `serial` behavior you'll also want to make the sequence owned by the table:

```
alter sequence your_seq owned by category.id;
```

Reading the [Serial Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) section of the manual might be fruitful.

---

I'd also recommend that you don't double quote your table and column names unless you have to. PostgreSQL will fold your identifiers to lower case so `id` and `"id"` will be the same thing but unnecessary quoting is a bad habit that can easily lead to a big mess of quotes everywhere.

Comment: How to define not null in serial and primary field ? 
Id INT NOT NULL SERIAL PRIMARY KEY is right ?

Comment: @Shesha: `id serial not null primary key`. `serial` is, more or less, a column type that takes care of the `int` and `default nextval...` stuff for you.

Answer (score 5):

If someone needs to modify an existing table to add a primary key with auto-increment:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN pk_column_name SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```