# How to make the Primary Key have X digits in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, auto-increment, postgresql-9.4

I am fairly new to SQL but have been working hard to learn. I am currently stuck on an issue with setting a primary key to have 8 digits no matter what.

I tried using `INT(8)` but that didn't work. Also `AUTO_INCREMENT` doesn't work in PostgreSQL but I saw there were a couple of data types that auto increment but I still have the issue of the keys not being long enough.

Basically I want to have numbers represent User IDs, starting at `10000000` and moving up. `00000001` and up would work too, it doesn't matter to me.

I saw an answer that was close to this, but it didn't apply to PostgreSQL unfortunately.

Hopefully my question makes sense, if not I'll try to clarify.

My code (which I am using from a website to try and make my own forum for a practice project) is:

```
CREATE Table users (
user_id     INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_name   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
user_pass   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
user_email  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
user_date   DATETIME NOT NULL,
user_level  INT(8) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX user_name_unique (user_name),
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) TYPE=INNODB;
```

It doesn't work in PostgreSQL (9.4 Windows x64 version). What do I do?

Comment: I was able to create the table using the code that I'll post below, but like I said it doesn't force the number of digits to 8 for the Primary Key (user ID) and won't automatically increase for each new user created:




`CREATE TABLE users (
 user_id  INT NOT NULL,
 user_name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 user_pass  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 user_email  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 user_date  DATE NOT NULL,
 user_level  INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
    );`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781111/postgresql-9-1-primary-key-autoincrement for auto increment columns in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Your other requirement is a bit weird. Why do you care how many digits the primary key has? If 1 as you say is a valid value, then keep an integer column, and format the value with 8 digits when you show it in a GUI.

Comment: Hey JP Moresmau, the reason I had asked for 8 digits is because I didn't want it to show up as 1, 2, 7, etc I'd prefer many digits. To be honest I didn't realize I can just leave them as small digits then fill in with zeroes like you said at the GUI level (like I said I am pretty new at SQL so I haven't worked with the frontend of things yet and how they look to users).

Comment: Unrelated but: `INT(8)` does ***not*** limit the values to 8 digits in MySQL. It's merely a _hint_ for a GUI application on how many digits the application should _display_. It does in no way constrain the data you can put into it. You can store the same range of values (up to a value of 2147483647) into a `int(1)` or `int(10)` column in MySQL

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing two aspects:

- the ***data type*** allowing certain ***values*** for your PK column
- the ***format*** you chose for display

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is a non-standard concept of MySQL, SQL Server uses `IDENTITY(1,1)`, etc.
Use a [**`serial`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517) column in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, ...
)
```

That's a pseudo-type implemented as `integer` data type with a column default drawing from an attached [`SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createsequence.html). `integer` is easily big enough for your case (-2147483648 to +2147483647).

If you really need to enforce numbers with a maximum of 8 decimal digits, add a [`CHECK` constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS):

```
CONSTRAINT id_max_8_digits CHECK (user_id BETWEEN 0 AND < 99999999)
```

To display the number in any fashion you desire - 0-padded to 8 digits, for your case, use [**`to_char()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE):

```
SELECT to_char(user_id, '00000000') AS user_id_8digit
FROM   users;
```

That's very fast. Note that the output is `text` now, not `integer`.
[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/60112/1)

A couple of other things are MySQL-specific in your code:

- `int(8)`: use [`int`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT).
- `datetime`: use [`timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html).
- <strike>`TYPE=INNODB`</strike>: just drop that.

Answer (score 1):

You could make user_id a serial type column and set the seed of this sequence to 10000000.

Comment: I looked up what you said and I was able to figure it out! Here is my code that I used, is there a better way to go about it? I added two entries to the database without inputting the User ID # and it did it automatically! I would show a screenshot but I don't think I can link here so here is my code:

`CREATE TABLE users (
 user_id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 user_name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 user_pass  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 user_email  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 user_date  DATE NOT NULL,
 user_level  INT NOT NULL
);
ALTER SEQUENCE users_user_id_seq RESTART WITH 10000000 INCREMENT BY 1;`

Comment: Here is how it looks in the database (hopefully I am allowed to link things) [link](http://i.imgur.com/vVjdrst.png)

Comment: Yes, it looks good. All the best. Do keep in mind that you will have to reseed the sequence to max(id) + 1 every time you restore the table from other database or input the id column manually. [This](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fixing_Sequences) page has more information.

Comment: @TavoloPerUno: I don't think you need to reseed sequences in any currently supported version of PostgreSQL. I know *I* don't need to.

Comment: I run postgres 9.4.1 too and I still have to fix the sequences after every insert operation that inputs values for any of these sequence columns, failing which the DB would greet me with a duplicate key value error on the next insert with no value for an id column.

Answer (score 1):

Why?

int(8) in mysql doesn't actually only store 8 digits, it only displays 8 digits

Postgres supports check constraints. You could use something like this:

```
create table foo (
  bar_id int primary key check ( 9999999 < bar_id and bar_id < 100000000 )
);
```

If this is for numbering important documents like invoices that shouldn't have gaps, then you shouldn't be using sequences / auto_increment